# Android - Problemas con botón de retroceso del móvil

Tags: android

Estoy teniendo problemas con el retroceso en la tecla del móvil. Al hacer retroceso desde la tecla mantiene la pantalla actual y la funde con la anterior, mezclando las dos.

¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

A las malas, ¿alguna sugerencia para anular el botón de retroceso del móvil en mi app?

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onBackPressed");

    //currentFragment must exist...
    if(currentFragment != null){


            /*
            use reflection to trigger a handleBackButton method in the     current plugin...not all
                plugins implement this method...but can as needed.

                In most cases the handleBackButton method should "go back" by popping the current
            fragment off the stack. In other cases it may do something all together different.

        */

        java.lang.reflect.Method backMethod = null;
        try{
            backMethod = currentFragment.getClass().getMethod("handleBackButton");
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onBackPressed. EXCEPTION (0): " + e.toString());
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
            BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onBackPressed. Current fragment does not have an \"onBackPressed\" method implemented");
        }

        //fire the handleBackButton method if we found it...
        if(backMethod != null){
            try{
                backMethod.invoke(currentFragment);
            }catch(Exception e){
                BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onBackPressed. EXCEPTION (1): " + e.toString());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, podrias facilitar algo de codigo para que te podamos ayudar?

Comment: Gracias. Editado

Comment: @CosasVarias se requiere un poco más de información de donde obtuviste ese método? debes realizar una transacción de Fragments

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que des a la flecha de volver, deberás hacer `finish()` para finalizar la `Activity` actual de la siguiente forma:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
     finish();
 }
```

Esto hará que se elimine la `Activity` actual, y no aparezca en la cola de retroceso.

Answer (score 0):

estas usando el método `onBackPressed()` pero mantiene la pantalla actual, en este caso estas usando `Fragment` y no `Activity` si fuera `Activity` simplemente terminarías la Activity actual con `finish()`:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    ...
    ...
    finish();
}
```

**En tu caso debes realizar una transacción del Fragmento**, el método que usas mediante reflection no esta reemplazando el Fragment por esa razón se ven dos Fragments encimados.

> /*
>               use reflection to trigger a handleBackButton method in the     current plugin...not all
>                   plugins implement this method...but can as needed.
>
> In most cases the handleBackButton method should "go back" by popping the current
>               fragment off the stack. In other cases it may do something all together different.
>
> */